# Populate spinner from database content (SQLite)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, spinner

How can I populate a spinner content from database (SQLite)

I have POJO: categories, contain id and name,
I have the table already, with a function to get the ArrayList like this:

```
public List<SetcardCategory> getAllSetcardCategory()
{
    List<SetcardCategory> setcardCategories = new ArrayList<SetcardCategory>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SETCARD_CATEGORIES;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            SetcardCategory setcardCategory = new SetcardCategory();
            setcardCategory.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex("id"))));
            setcardCategory.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));

            // adding to tags list
            setcardCategories.add(setcardCategory);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return setcardCategories;
}
```

Then on Activity I call it like this:

```
List<SetcardCategory> setcardCategories = db.getAllSetcardCategory();
    ArrayAdapter<SetcardCategory> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<SetcardCategory>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, setcardCategories);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.setcardCategory);
    sItems.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

when I run it, it loads string like this: "schema.SetcardCategory@22293c98"  and many others values similar to that.

How can I populate the spinner to show the name field as a label, and id field as the value that we fetch to save into DB?

Comment: in the pojo class overide tostring method and return the value you want to display in the spinner

Comment: you can do that just in 5 lines of code by using `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**
Overide the toString method in your SetcardCategory class

```
class SetcardCategory {
...
...
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**
If you just want to show the name, Just pick name only from DB

```
public List<String> getAllSetcardCategory()
    {
        List<String> setcardCategories = new ArrayList<String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SETCARD_CATEGORIES;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // adding to tags list
                setcardCategories.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return setcardCategories;
    }
```

And create Array Adapter as

```
List<String> setcardCategories = db.getAllSetcardCategory();
    ArrayAdapter<SetcardCategory> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<SetcardCategory>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, setcardCategories);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: by using this one, i cannot fetch the id, right? Manoj kumar answer fit the situation better

Comment: I given both solutions. I have given the second solution because of looks like you only need the name.

Comment: oh ya, im so sorry, i saw Manoj answer first, but actually your answer posted first.

Comment: @Gabriel no, it does not provide valid row IDs in the adapter, for that you should use `CursorAdapter` - for example `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Answer (score 3):

```
class Pojo{
 private String name;
  @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

do it like this in the pojo class, so this will return a value for the object when it uses the to string method in the adapter, to load the data